# Is there a way to see how many files one Visual Studio Project has?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, build, clang, visual-studio-2019

I want to count all the files which are part of one Visual Studio Project, is there a way to do that? By the number of files I mean all the files that are included in the building process of some specific project.

For example, I want to know how many files are compiled when building this clang project. I have Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.3.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows? you can simply right click > Open folder in File explorer > right click on folder > properties to see the files count, size etc.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure If I was clear enough, but I edited my question, I want the number of files which are being compiled when building the specific project.